# Why does this scatter plot have squares instead of crosses?

Tags: python, qt, graph, scatter-plot, pyqtgraph

I'm using pyqtgraph to create scatter plots, when I create a scatterplot like this:

```
scatter = pg.ScatterPlotItem([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], symbol='x', brush='r', size=10)
```

then I get the expected behavior (crosses):

[image]

The only issue with this version of creating a scatter plot is that I can't control the color of each individual symbol (this ability is necessary for my project).  I did a bit of research and I came across a way to specify details of each individual data point using a dictionaries.

Here's my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import pyqtgraph as pg

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

graph = pg.PlotWidget()

orderScatterDict = []

for i in range(4):
    color = 'b'
    if i % 2 == 1:
        color = 'r'
    #change the time to be what it actually is
    spot_dic = {'pos': (i, i), 'size': 10, 'symbol':'x',
                'pen': {'color': color, 'width': 10}}
    orderScatterDict.append(spot_dic)


scatter = pg.ScatterPlotItem()  #scatter = pg.ScatterPlotItem([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], symbol='x', brush='r', size=10)

graph.addItem(scatter)
scatter.setData(orderScatterDict)
graph.show()
app.exec_()
```

However when I do this, the symbols are all squares:

[image]

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Could you post a picture of the outputted plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pen `width` is the same as the `size` of the crosses, resulting in fat crosses that almost look like squares. Change `width` to something smaller (or remove it completely), and you will see the crosses again.